# CodeIgniter Validation Rules for Email and Password

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I was used to coding application with CodeIgniter and I'm a total newbie. I just started to learn CodeIgniter 3.0, and and reached to validation rules.

I notice that `xss_clean` is now gone from the validation class, so what rules should I use in the validation of email and password? Using just `trim`, `valid_email`, and required is enough for security?

Sorry if that question has been asked, but I searched around and I see old topics where people is using `xss_clean`.

Comment: xss_clean is deprecated in Codeigniter 3.0. its no  more in form_validation library. old one also not as much useful to completely prevent XSS. You should have custom function to clean userdata. Better clean userdata while printing on html.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Include Email Helper:

`$this->load->helper('email');`

For Email:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email|xss_clean');
```

Or you can also use PHP Filter for email validation as

`filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);`

For Password Expression

```
   public function chk_password_expression($str)

    {

    if (1 !== preg_match("/^.*(?=.{6,})(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*$/", $str))

    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('chk_password_expression', '%s must be at least 6 characters and must contain at least one lower case letter, one upper case letter and one digit');
        return FALSE;
    }

    else

    {
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

To call the function you should use:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules(  'password', 'Password', 'trim|required|min_length[6]|max_length[15]|callback_chk_password_expression');
```

**Note: chk_password_expression should be in same class controller or in parent class. Email helper should be included as $this->load->helper('email');**

Comment: Isn't xss_clean depreciated in CodeIgniter 3? Also, what does the password expression do?

Comment: In addition to that, in the email helper class, it says "The Email helper is DEPRECATED and is currently only kept for backwards compatibility."

Comment: http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/email_helper.html#loading-this-helper check here how to use this. you can also use filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);